# Equations of condition

Tags: maxima-minima

In this example(Calculus Made Easy pg 126): 
$\frac{4R^2-2x^2}{\sqrt{4R^2-x^2}}=0$
simplifies to $4R^2-2x^2=0$ and therefore 
$x=R\sqrt{2}$
Why does the denominator not come into play when we equate to zero?

Comment: It does come into play. Multiply both sides by the denominator, what do you get?

Comment: zero divided by any real number equals zero - provided $x>2R$ you won't have an issue.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks I feel like I should have seen that before I asked.